# В чем разница при итерировании for(var item in data){...} и data[i]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Господа.

у меня происходит вот что:

Я в методе $(document).ready( ... ) REST'ом получаю (GET'ом, через $.ajax(...) ) список item'ов.
Для проверки я делаю что то вроде

```
console.log("json data:" + data);
```

и

```
console.log("length=" + data.length );
```

и обе строки печатают в лог адекватные вещи.

По смыслу data - это некий array элемкентов.
И я могу нормально обратиться к всяким свойствам этих элементов, написав, например,

```
var tst = data[1].text;
```

Но.

если я пытаюсь итерироваться по элементам array'я внутри цикла

```
  for (var item in data){
    console.log("item.text=" + item.text);
  }
```

то я получаю вместо ожидаемого текста надпись

```
item.text=undefined
```

В чем же отличие итерирования for (var item in data){ ... } от data[i]?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Если у вас массив объектов, используйте forEach. for in обходит свойства объекта

Comment: `(for var item of data) { ...` См. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in и https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Большое спасибо,  Vearo! Помогло!